# matplotlib.animation plotting inside a loop

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have data being provided to me through a socket connection from three sensor nodes, there are three subplots each for temperature, voltage and humidity values. The temp subplot should plot the temperature values from each node. Likewise for humidity and voltage. Here is the code I have written:

```
import socket
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import pickle


fig = plt.figure()
temp_plot = fig.add_subplot(3,1,1)
volt_plot = fig.add_subplot(3,1,2)
pres_plot = fig.add_subplot(3,1,3)


maclist=['xyz01','xyz02','xyz03']
temp=[]
volt=[]
time=[]
pres=[]


ip = 'server IP address'

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect((ip,10030))
print 'connection established to server...'

def animate(i):
  global sock  
  info = sock.recv(1024)
  info = pickle.loads(info)

  ind = maclist.index(info['MAC'])
  if len(temp[ind]) == 10: #to make sure every time 10 points are plotted
   temp[ind].pop(0)
   time[ind].pop(0)
   volt[ind].pop(0)
   pres[ind].pop(0)

  temp[ind].append(info['TEMP'])
  time[ind].append(info['TIME'])
  volt[ind].append(info['VOLT'])
  pres[ind].append(info['PRES'])
  temp_plot.clear()
  volt_plot.clear()
  pres_plot.clear()

  for i in range(len(maclist)):
    temp_plot(time[i],temp[i])
    volt_plot(time[i],volt[i])
    pres_plot(time[i],pres[i])

if __name__ == '__main__' :
   ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animate,interval = 100)
   plt.show()
```

> info =
>   {'MAC':'xyz01','TIME':21.4131,'TEMP':27.0,'VOLT':2.5,'PRES':892}

temp,volt,time and pres are lists which contain sublists,
for ex - temp[0] contains a list of temperature values from node0.

This code gives me an error, which I doubt is due to trying to plot inside the loop

> 'temp_plot(time[i],temp[i])
>   TypeError: 'AxesSubplot' object is not
>   callable '

could anyone kindly help me regarding this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`temp_plot` is the subplot you want to plot to. You cannot call the subplot itself. Just as you wouldn't write `plt(x,y)` or `ax(x,y)`, but instead `plt.plot(x,y)` or `ax.plot(x,y)`; here you need

```
temp_plot.plot(time[i],temp[i])
volt_plot.plot(time[i],volt[i])
pres_plot.plot(time[i],pres[i])
```